# Problem to read/write on redis cache aws with TLS activated

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, redis

I'm trying to write dataframe on redis cache aws service with TLS activated and got this message:

**ERR AUTH  called without any password configured for the default user. Are you sure your configuration is correct ?**

**SparkSession Configs:**

```
val spark = SparkSession.builder()
           .config("spark.redis.host", "anyhost")
           .config("spark.redis.port", "6379")
           .config("spark.redis.user", "default")
           .config("spark.redis.auth", "xxxxx")
           .config("spark.redis.ssl",  "true")
           .getOrCreate()
```

**Dataframe Read:**

```
val df = spark.read.format("org.apache.spark.sql.redis")
        .option("table", "client")
        .option("key.column", "id")
        .load()

df.show()
```

if I desactivate the TLS, it's working!